# Python, How to Load Video File on RAM?

Tags: python, qt

Hi is this scenario possible?

In My Server-PC i got this library of movie files,
then
In one of my Client-PC's, They Access or Copy a movie file from the Server-PC BUT stores it only on the RAM/Memory?
If This is possible How can i Read/Open/Play it?

Im trying to make a program (In Python 2.6 with QT) for students in our schools that plays the video, but dont leave a file on their PC's since those Video Material is licensed by the owner. and doesn't want other 
school to use it, since's its only made for the school itself.

please im open to any kind of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get an abundant Audio/Video Resources out in [this](http://wiki.python.org/moin/AudioVideo) link. The Particular thing that you wan't to achieve is called Audio/Video Streaming. There are few libraries that provide this functionality one of which is [Flumotion](http://www.flumotion.net/). If you have not worked or do not know what Media Streaming is, just fiddle with VLC which provided the same functionality as you are desiring. This will give you an idea what you intend to develop.

Comment: it seems Flumotion is only for linux, im using windows XP7